# Proving that two projections are at most distance 1 apart

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I am trying to solve the very first problem in ["The Blue Book"](http://www.math.ku.dk/~rordam/K-theory.html) by M. Rørdam. The problem is the following:

- Let $p$ and $q$ be projections in a $C^*$-algebra $A$. Prove that $\Vert p - q \Vert \leq 1$.

To me, it seems like this problem should have a simple and elegant solution, but I am not able to produce it. I have managed to reduce the problem slightly as follows.

Put $s = p-pq$ and $ t = q-pq$. By adding and subtracting $pq$ we obtain $\Vert p - q \Vert = \Vert (p-pq) - (q-pq) \Vert = \Vert s-t \Vert.$ It is straightforward to check that $s^*t = 0 = t^*s$ and that $st^* = 0 = ts^*$. This means that if we realize $A$ on a Hilbert space, then the operators $s$ and $t$ have orthogonal range and domain. I would now like to conclude that $\Vert p - q \Vert = \Vert s-t \Vert \overset{?}{\leq} \max\{ \Vert s \Vert, \Vert t \Vert \} = 1$. The last equality holds since $\Vert s \Vert = \Vert p(1_{\tilde A} - q) \Vert \leq 1$ since $p$ and $1_{\tilde A} - q$ are both projections, and similarly for $t$.

So, what I really would like to know is whether the bound above actually holds, and if so, why. Namely:

- Whether two operators $S,T \in \mathcal{B}(H)$ satisfying $S^*T = 0$ and $ST^* = 0$ also satisfy $\Vert S-T \Vert \leq \max\{ \Vert S \Vert, \Vert T \Vert \}$?

Alternative proofs (or mere suggestions) of the originial problem is also appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complement Jake's answer, here is the answer to the OP's question:

If $TS^*=0$, then $T^*TS^*S=0$. If follows that the range projections of $T^*T$ and $S^*S$ are orthogonal to each other. Given $x\in H$, we write $x=x_T+x_S+x_0$, where $x_T\in\text{ran}\,T^*T$, $x_S\in\text{ran}\,S^*S$. 
Using also $S^*T=0$,
\begin{align}
\|T-S\|^2&=\|(T-S)^*(T-S)\|=\|T^*T+S^*S\|\\ \ \\
&=\sup\{\langle (T^*T+S^*S)x,x\rangle:\ \|x\|=1\}\\ \ \\
&=\sup\{\langle T^*Tx_T,x_T\rangle+\langle S^*Sx_S,x_S\rangle:\ \|x\|=1\}\\ \ \\
&\leq\sup\{\|T\|^2\|x_T\|^2+\|S^2\|\|x_S\|^2:\ \|x\|=1\}\\ \ \\
&\leq\max\{\|T\|,\|S\|\}^2\,\sup\{\|x_T\|^2+\|x_S\|^2:\ \|x\|=1\}\\ \ \\
&\leq\max\{\|T\|,\|S\|\}^2.
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

Let $p,q$ be projections in some C*-algebra $A$.  Then $\sigma(p)\subseteq\{0,1\}$.  By the functional calculus, $\sigma(\frac{1}{2}-p)\subseteq\{-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\}$ and hence $\frac{1}{2}-p$ is self-adjoint (spectral radius equals norm), which implies that $||\frac{1}{2}-p||=\frac{1}{2}$.  Thus $||p-q||=||(\frac{1}{2}-p)-(\frac{1}{2}-q)||\leq\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=1$

Edit: This assumes $A$ is unital.  If not, pass to the unitization.  Since the norm on the unitization extends the norm on $A$, the result holds.

Comment: $(\frac 1 2 - p) - (q-\frac 12) \neq p-q$ but of course the argument works. Another argument is that $-I \leq p - q \leq I$ where $I$ denotes the identity.

Comment: That's a nice trick! I'm glad there is a simple proof of this fact. Strictly speaking $p$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ should be interchanged as mentioned by @Epsilon. I am not familiar with many results on positivty, but I think I can convince myself that $-I \leq p - q \leq I$. Is it a general result which says that $-a \leq b \leq a \implies \Vert b \Vert \leq \Vert a \Vert$?

Comment: In general, if $0 \leq a \leq b$ you have that $\lVert a \lVert \leq \lVert b \lVert$. In our case the following argument is needed: $\sigma(p-q) \subset [-1,1]$ and $p-q$ is self-adjoint. Therefore it holds that  $\lVert p-q \lVert \leq 1$ by the spectral radius formula.

Answer (score 1):

A different proof:

$$(p-q)^2=p(1-q)+q(1-p),$$ 
and then it is straightforward to show with induction (square at each step) that 
$$(p-q)^{2^k}=(p(1-q))^{2^{k-1}}+(q(1-p))^{2^{k-1}}$$
for each positive integer $k$. By the triangle inequality and the inequality $\|ab\|\leq\|a\|\|b\|$, this implies that $$\|(p-q)^{2^k}\|\leq 2$$ for all positive integers $k$.  Because $p-q$ is self-adjoint, $\|(p-q)^{2^k}\|=\|p-q\|^{2^k}$, so the inequality above holding as $k\to \infty$ implies $\|p-q\|\leq 1$.

---

Although this is rather ad hoc and a proof analyzing the spectrum generalizes better, this proof has the property that it uses only the basic definitions.  E.g., the fact that $\|a^{2^k}\|=\|a\|^{2^k}$ when $a$ is self-adjoint follows immediately from the C*-identity $\|x^*x\|=\|x\|^2$.

---

Here's a brief recap using the notation in the question. The norm is at most $1$ because

$$\forall k\in\mathbb N, \|p-q\|^{2^k}=\|(p-q)^{2^{k}}\|=\|s^{2^{k-1}}+(t^*)^{2^{k-1}}\|\leq 2.$$